# Process ID not printing in python logging

Tags: python, logging

[According to the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html), it should be a simple matter when adding the process id to the statements in the log.  Here is what I have:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(format='%(process)d %(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    filename = ns.logFile, level=ns.loggingLevel,
                    datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

This prints out nicely, except the process id is missing:

```
2021-08-13 11:36:01 DEBUG    Got here!!!9
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.basicConfig) `logging.basicConfig`

> does nothing if the root logger already has handlers configured, unless the keyword argument force is set to True. The functions debug(), info(), warning(), error() and critical() will call basicConfig() automatically if no handlers are defined for the root logger.

I suspect handlers are already added before your configuration. So I think you will have to force your configuration with :

```py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
        force=True,
        format='%(process)d %(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s', 
        filename = ns.logFile, level=ns.loggingLevel, datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
       )
```